# Why shapefiles created with sf package (in R) do not display same CRS in ArcMap?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, r, sf

I have created a polygon shapefile in ArcMap using 7 points(lat,lon) then read this shapefile into R to obtain the CRS. I then created a shape file in R using the `sf` package (and the 7 points) and used the CRS obtained from the ArcMap shapefile. When I bring the shapefile created in R into ArcMap I get a warning regarding different coordinate systems. Why would this happen?

My steps:

7 points (lon and lat) where point 1 = point 7 (closed loop). Create a polygon shapefile in ArcMap and display. Properties in ArcMap show : *Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_North_American_1983 Datum: D_North_American_1983*

In R I use `rgdal` to read in shapefile and obtain CRS

```
cashes <- rgdal::readOGR(dsn="path",layer="shapefile") 
cashes@proj4string 
This results in : "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 "
```

Now I create the shapefile in R using the `sf` package (I could use %>%)

```
Rshapefile <- readxl::read_xlsx(path,sheet="cashes")
Rshapefile <- sf::st_as_sf(Rshapefile,coords=c("lon","lat"),crs="+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 ")
```

Edit: At this point if i inspect Rshapefile i get this
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs
Note: +datum=NAD83 is dropped.

```
Rshapefile <- dplyr::summarize(Rshapefile,geometry = sf::st_combine(geometry))
Rshapefile <- sf::st_cast(Rshapefile,"POLYGON")

sf::st_write(Rshapefile,dsn=path,layer="Rshapefile",driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

I then bring this `Rshapefile` into ArcMap and the coordinate systems are different. When I view the properties in ArcMap they show: *Geographic Coordinate System: GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980) Datum: D_unknown*

Why is this? I must be doing something wrong but I can't figure out what!

Comment: I can't help you with this question, but thank you for including the references to the packages for each function.

Comment: Have you checked the CRS at each stage of manipulating Rshapefile after first assigning the CRS?

Comment: `dns=path` should be `dsn=path`. Not sure that fixes it but at least it makes your code run properly.

Comment: @Spacedman. Just a typo. Code reads dsn.@Simbamangu I have editied the post to show this. The +datum = NAD83 is dropped. Not sure why or it it matters.